# Simple script not working on my html code for my site

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning HTML and Javascript, but it seems I did something wrong and I can't figure it out, why won't my script work? It is supposed to change the size of the image when you hover over with the mouse. I'm just investigating to learn how to do stuff.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Kikito's Sprites  </title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:#ffc299">
        <div>
                <h1 style="color:white"> Kikito Loco Sprite Showcaserino </h1>


                <img onmouseover="descriptiveTextImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" src="monigoteTransparencia.png" alt="Amicable Anthony" style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:-50px;width:300px;height:300px;">               
                <img src="ballinBob.png" alt="Ballin Bob" style="position:absolute;top:90px;left:130px;width:300px;height:300px;">

                <img src="severedArm.png" alt="just some pixel gore" style= "position:absolute;top:350px;left:-40px;width:300px;height:300px;">
                <img src="shinySkin.png" alt="Shiny Skin" style="position:absolute;top:350px;left:200px;width:300px;height:300px;">
                <img src="bigBall.png" alt="a cannonball" style= "position:absolute;top:640px;left:-40px;width:300px;height:300px;">
                </div>


         <script>
             function descriptiveTextImg(x) 
             {
             x.style.width = 400px;
             x.style.height = 400px;
             }

             function normalImg(x) 
             {
             x.style.width = 300px;
             x.style.height = 300px;
             }

         </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use js console for view errors: `Ctrl+Shift+J` for most of browsers.

Comment: ok thanks! I didn't know that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change all occurrences of `300px` to `'300px'`, etc.

`style.width` and `style.height` expects string values. `300px` is not valid javascript code. If you need to use number, i.e. if you are using variables, you'll need to concatenate this into a string:

```
x.style.width = someIntWidth + 'px';
```

Comment: OMG, that worked, thank you so much. The problem is, the image gets bigger when hovering but it also "moves", is it actually possible to make it ''stay'' when it gets bigger?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use css for it. No need of JS

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b66cx6ce/)

```
img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.4,1.4);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! where would your code go? Sorry, I'm super noob